# Compute a probability using stochastic simulation

Tags: r, probability, mathematical-statistics, simulation, stochastic-processes

My problem is to solve the following optimisation problem using  GA (Genetic Algorithm)and stochastic simulation. The goal is to solve the maximisation problem :  \begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\text{Max}_{x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}} \qquad &\mathbb{E}[\xi_{1}x_{1}+\xi_{2}x_{2}+\cdots+\xi_{n}x_{n}]\\
 \text{s.t.} \qquad
&\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
   &  \mathbb{P}r\{(0.4-(\xi_{1}x_{1}+\xi_{2}x_{2}+\cdots+\xi_{n}x_{n}))\geqslant r\}\leqslant \alpha(r)\\
   &  \forall r\geqslant 0\\ 
   &x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=1\\
   &x_{1}  \qquad  \forall i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}.\\
  \end{array}
\right.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $ n=5 $, $ \ \xi_{i}\sim N(\mu_{i},\sigma_{i}) $ with $\mu_{i}\in\{0.1, 0.2, 0.3,0.4,0.5\}$, $\sigma_{i}=1$  and  $ \ \alpha(r)=\dfrac{1}{(r+1.1)^{4}} $, $\ r\geqslant 0 $.

Comment: Is the "$r$" after the "$\mathbb{P}$" a reference to $r$ or did you intend to write $\Pr$ ("probability of") instead? And presumably $b$ and the $x_i$ are constants, right? Finally, your question appears to have nothing to do with stochastic simulation but that is mentioned in the title: have you left out some important details?

Comment: The main goal is to solve the following portfolio problem :  \begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\text{Max}_{x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}} \qquad &\mathbb{E}[\xi_{1}x_{1}+\xi_{2}x_{2}+\cdots+\xi_{n}x_{n}]\\
 \text{s.t.} \qquad
&\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
   &  \mathbb{P}r\{(b-(\xi_{1}x_{1}+\xi_{2}x_{2}+\cdots+\xi_{n}x_{n}))\geqslant r\}\leqslant \alpha(r)\\
   &  \forall r\geqslant 0\\ 
   &x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=1\\
   &x_{1}  \qquad  \forall i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}.\\
  \end{array}
\right.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Because $\mathbb{E}[\xi_i]=0$ for all $i$, the $x_i$ are constants, and expectation is linear, $\mathbb{E}[\xi_{1}x_{1}+\xi_{2}x_{2}+\cdots+\xi_{n}x_{n}]$ = $x_1\mathbb{E}[\xi_1]+\cdots+x_n\mathbb{E}[\xi_n]$ = $x_1\times 0+\cdots+x_n\times 0=0$ no matter what. That's not much of a portfolio :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $\xi_i \sim N(\mu_i, 1)$ are independent, then $\sum \xi_i x_i \sim N(\sum \mu_i x_i, \sum x_i^2)$. Thus your probability question can be computed as

$$\begin{align*}
\Pr\left(b - \sum \xi_i x_i \ge r\right)
   &= \Pr\left(\sum \xi_i x_i \le b - r\right)
\\ &= \Pr\left(\frac{\sum \xi_i x_i - \sum \mu_i x_i}{\sqrt{\sum x_i^2}} \le \frac{b - r - \sum \mu_i x_i}{\sqrt{\sum x_i^2}}\right)
\\  &= \Phi\left( \frac{b - r - \sum \mu_i x_i}{\sqrt{\sum x_i^2}} \right)
\end{align*}$$

where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal.

Denoting $\mu$ as the vector of means and $x$ the vector of $x_i$s, your objective is $\mathbb{E}[\sum x_i \xi_i] = \mu^T x$.

The first constraint is then that $x$ must satisfy $\Phi\left( \frac{b - r - \mu^T x}{\lVert x \rVert} \right) \le \alpha(r) \quad \forall r > 0$. The others are simple: $1^T x = 1$, and presumably your last constraint is meant to be $x_i \ge 0 \quad \forall i$.

Note that this constraint is a function of only $\mu^T x$ and $\lVert x \rVert$. For a fixed $\lVert x \rVert$, and assuming an $\alpha(r)$ generally like the one you specified on the other question of $(1.1 - r)^{-4}$, I'm pretty sure there is a certain value of $\mu^T x$ for which all lower values do not satisfy the constraint and all higher values do. Cauchy-Schwarz gives us $\lvert \mu^T x \rvert \le \lVert \mu \rVert \lVert x \rVert$, so for a given $\lVert x \rVert$ we can binary-search for the minimum value of $\mu^T x$ such that the constraint is satisfied.

I don't have time to work this out right now, but I *think* we can use this to figure out the shape of the constraint set and/or get a projection onto it to solve your optimization problem.

Comment: This is correct, but what if $n=5$ and $\xi_{i}$ are $N(0.1,1)$ ,$N(0.2,1)$,$N(0.4,1)$, $N(0.6,1)$,$N(0.8,1)$.

Comment: That changes the question profoundly, Lea.  Please modify your question to show that's what you really intended to ask.

Comment: Dougal, this is exactly the way to do it, but is it possible to have some package or some code in R to do it